# Magento Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

Tags: php, magento

Actually I am transferring Magento application of SSL certificate with https type from Blue Host to Godaddy Server.

I purchased SSL Certificate now, my website can open but it is giving error.
I went into var/report/xxxxxxxx file, It gives below errors.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:105:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)";i:1;s:2633:"#0 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(109): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(478): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#12 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#13 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1183): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#14 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#15 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#16 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(413): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#17 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#18 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /home/content/43/6301943/html/beta/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

I am working first time on Megento. So I dont know how to solve above errors.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what about your status? have you fixed?

Comment: No , Until I did not fix.

Comment: I think, Given answer may be your answer. Double check your DB connection

Comment: I have checked again. DB Credentials are correct

Comment: check your host. It may be differ. <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
create one sample php file to connect your DB with given credential in local.xml

Comment: Is MySQL up and running?

Comment: Yes It was the Database Connectivity Error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that your database details are not correct. Go to app/etc/local.xml and correct your database details.

Comment: I think I have given right parameters for connecting to the db. I am uploading this site on Godaddy Hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your mysql server then it will be fixed.